# Pass no char to a function that is expecting it in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am working with Haskell and I have defined the following type

```
--Build type Transition--
data Transition = Transition {
     start_state :: Int, 
     symbol :: Char, 
     end_state :: Int
} deriving Show
```

and I would like to be able to define the following Transition

```
Transition 0 '' 1
```

which would be mean "a transition given by no symbol" (I need it to compute the epsilon closure of a NFA). How can I do this?
Thank you!

Comment: In that case I would remodel it such that `symbol :: Maybe Char`.

Comment: Incidentally the word you're looking for in the typical description of an NFA is Transition, not Transaction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well the idea of defining a type is that every value you pass to that field is a "member" of that type. `Char` only contains only characters (and the empty string is *not* a character) and `undefined` (but it is advisable *not* to use `undefined` here).

Usually in case you want to make values optional, you can use a `Maybe a` type instead, so:

```
data Transaction = Transaction {
     start_state :: Int, 
     symbol :: Maybe Char, 
     end_state :: Int
} deriving Show
```

So now we can pass two kinds of values: `Nothing` which thus should be interpreted as "*no character*", or `Just x`, with `x` a character, and this thus acts as a character, so in your case, that would be:

```
Transaction 0 Nothing 1
```

`Maybe` is also an instance of `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad`, which should make working with `Maybe` types quite convenient (yes it can sometimes introduce some extra work, but by using `fmap`, etc. the amount of pattern matching shifting to `Maybe Char` should be rather low).

> **Note**: like @amalloy says, an `NFA` (and `DFA`) has `Transition`s, not `Transaction`s.